# It's Just Simple Math!

Tags: code-golf, number, natural-language

## Task

Your boss is on another crusade for 'efficiency.' He wants to encourage the use of numbers with fewer syllables, so that they're easier to *discuss* in meetings. If you want to take some time off work, you're boss would prefer you take `9` days instead of `7`. You're boss would prefer a credit card expense of `$99,502` over `$77,601`

### Input

You can chose your input format for the numbers, if you want to take in `7/9` or `seven/nine` it's completely up to you

### Output

Output whichever number has the least syllables. ***CATCH!*** You must output the answer in the same format you chose for the input. So if your program takes in `7/9` as input, it must output `9`. And if your program takes in binary numbers as the input, such as `0000111/0001001`, then it must output the answer as `0001001`

### Examples

I used [howmanysyllables.com](https://www.howmanysyllables.com/) to find the amount of syllables in each number:

| `Input` | `Syllables` | `Output` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `7\9` | `2 vs 1` | `9` |
| `ninety nine\one hundred and five` | `3 vs 5` | `ninety nine` |
| `0111101\1100011` | `3 vs 3` | `0111101 1100011` |
| `seventy seven thousand six hundred and one\ninety one thousand five hundred and two` | `12 vs 10` | `ninety one thousand five hundred and two` |
| `10011111111011\10111111111111` | `10 vs 11` | `10011111111011` |
| `13\15` | `2 vs 2` | `13 15` |

### Additional rules

1. Numbers must include `and` where appropriate. For example, `105` should be calculated as `one hundred and five` instead of `one hundred five`. I know some people might include `and` more than others when pronouncing numbers, so this is open to change in future depending on feedback!
2. If both numbers have the same number of syllables, output both numbers in the format you took them in
3. The input will only ever be a positive integer

### Numbers/Syllables

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12 = 1 syllables

> 7,13,14,15,16,18,19,20 = 2 syllables

> 11,17,21,22,23,24,25,26 = 3 syllables

> 27 = 4 syllables

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest program wins!**

Comment: Please include a table for the number of syllables each digit has. Also I don't think anyone is going to use the full text version if it's optional

Comment: @mousetail It might be shorter, because you might be able to count the vowels (with minor fixes) and it'll be shorter than hardcoding the table

Comment: @mousetail added one examples to the question

Comment: @Philippos 99,502 would be converted to ninety nine thousand five hundred and two. I'll update the question so that it's restricted to only positive integers

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/177586/how-many-syllables-in-that-number, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32381/convert-english-to-a-number, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71681/convert-english-to-a-number-without-built-ins-or-libraries

Comment: What is the highest integer that we need to support?

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E`, 120 bytes

```
h;s/n//g;s/[ls]e/##/g;s/ve/-/g;s/[aeiou]+/#/g;s/y/#/g;s/[^#,]//g;G;s/^(#*)#+,\1\n.*,//;s/^(#*),\1#+.(.*),.*/\2/;s/.*\n//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY3BDoIwEETv/kYvWEo3evVs/AgKCUlXaGK2hm0J/Ly1gN412WR23sxmGW3VU0xpuDAQQJ@lfnCDIMRmJoRqpx06H5sSdr58tG6Fata7WzZtIeRRlMqcDGmpAL4sE1HqQudNSzDnNdDS5IcphWFEHCLZEW1Hlt0clrubUDFOSGHZ5PBTK/jIOfyrnMcTvvwzOE@cqusb)